# Cambio de tipo de datos de columnas en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

De ante mano agradezco la ayuda, resulta que en una base de datos de posgresql cambie el tipo de dato de una columna de tipo timestap without zona horaria por el tipo timestap with zona horaria, este cambio elimino la parte de la fecha que se reflejaba en los datos y dejo el formato de hora, aunque vuelvo a cambiar el tipo de dato los datos no regresan a ser como antes, mi pregunta es como recuperar la parte de fecha en los datos, cabe decir que tengo otra columna en donde esta solamente el la fecha en tipo date

Comment: Muy buenas Juan Jose. Seria de utilidad que pusieras el ejemplo de codigo o ejemplo de las tablas. Creo que se de lo que hablas y podriamos ayudarte, si pudieramos visualizar el problema seria de gran utilidad

Comment: gracias amigo, resulta que el error fue sucedía porque me equivoque en el tipo de dato cuando hice el cambio y por tal motivo la columna solo dejo el registro de la hora, afortunadamente pude devolver el campo a un timestamp y recuperar la parte de la fecha con otras columna y consultas, agradezco la respuesta amigo :)